# Register a service so Resolve(args) passes args as dumb, positional arguments?

Tags: dryioc

I have an `IFormFactory` in my Windows Forms project with parameterized methods that return concrete `Form` subclasses. I used to use `Ninject.Extensions.Factory`'s `Bind<IFormFactory>().ToFactory()` to bind the factory to a dynamically generated proxy implementation. (When calling a method on the interface, Ninject would automatically call the constructor with the most matching arguments.)

I am trying to replicate this setup in DryIoc, but I'm having problems with passing the arguments to the forms' constructor. DryIoc treats the arguments to `Resolve(args)` as "replacement" dependencies, but I want to strictly use these arguments as "dumb" arguments to the constructor. Example:

```cs
public interface IFormFactory
{
    MyForm MyForm(string word, int number);
    MyForm MyForm(string word, int number, bool flag);
}

public class FormFactory : IFormFactory
{
    private readonly IResolver m_resolver;
    private readonly MethodInfo m_method1;
    private readonly MethodInfo m_method2;

    public FormFactory(IContainer container)
    {
        m_resolver = container;

        // I reflect over the methods on IFormFactory
        m_method1 = typeof(IFormFactory).GetMethod(nameof(IFormFactory.MyForm), new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(int) });
        m_method2 = typeof(IFormFactory).GetMethod(nameof(IFormFactory.MyForm), new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(int), typeof(bool) });

        // I do this dynamically, by counting parameters
        var constructor1 = m_method1.ReturnType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(IService), typeof(string), typeof(int) });
        var constructor2 = m_method2.ReturnType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(IService), typeof(string), typeof(int), typeof(bool) });

        // make a registration for each method that calls the selected constructor
        container.Register(
            m_method1.ReturnType,
            made: Made.Of(FactoryMethod.Of(constructor1)),
            serviceKey: m_method1);
        container.Register(
            m_method2.ReturnType,
            made: Made.Of(FactoryMethod.Of(constructor2)),
            serviceKey: m_method2);
    }

    public MyForm MyForm(string word, int number)
    {
        return (MyForm)m_resolver.Resolve(m_method1.ReturnType, new object[] { word, number }, serviceKey: m_method1);
    }

    public MyForm MyForm(string word, int number, bool flag)
    {
        return (MyForm)m_resolver.Resolve(m_method2.ReturnType, new object[] { word, number, flag }, serviceKey: m_method2);
    }
}

public interface IService { }
public class ServiceImpl : IService { }

public class MyForm
{
    public MyForm(IService service, string word, int number) { Console.WriteLine("constructor1"); }
    public MyForm(IService service, string word, int number, bool flag) { Console.WriteLine("constructor2"); }
}

void Main()
{
    using (var container = new Container())
    {
        container.Register<IService, ServiceImpl>();
        container.Register<IFormFactory, FormFactory>(reuse: Reuse.Singleton);

        var factory = container.Resolve<IFormFactory>();

        // this works because DryIoc uses these parameters as "dependencies" for the constructor
        factory.MyForm("word", 1);

        // this throws
        factory.MyForm(null, 2, true);
    }
}
```

Passing `null` to any of the arguments throws because DryIoc wants to supply a "dependency".

```
ContainerException: Unable to resolve String as parameter "word" with passed arguments [null]
  in MyForm {ServiceKey=MyForm MyForm(System.String, Int32, Boolean)} FactoryId=46 with passed arguments [null] IsResolutionCall
  from Container without Scope
Where no service registrations found
  and no dynamic registrations found in 0 of Rules.DynamicServiceProviders
  and nothing found in 0 of Rules.UnknownServiceResolvers
```

I thought of calling the constructor and resolving each dependency explicitly, but it seems this has a lot of disadvantages for contextual bindings, reuse, etc?

```cs
    public MyForm MyForm(string word, int number, bool flag)
    {
        return new MyForm(
            m_resolver.Resolve<IService>(),
            word,
            number,
            flag);
    }
```

Is it possible to craft a registration that will pass `args` as dumb arguments instead of treating them as dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may resolve as Func inside your MyForm methods:

```
public MyForm MyForm(string word, int number) { 
    return m_resolver.Resolve<Func<string, int, MyForm>>(serviceKey: m_method1)
    .Invoke(word, number);
}
```

Moreover you may inject and store these Funcs in the FormFactory ctor, and just call them from the factory methods.

Comment: Thanks! That does seem to work. I expected it to be the same as calling Resolve(args). Would like to see how the Func wrapper is implemented.